# Showing edited content

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am fetching content from Database and displaying it in Div. I have the following code and Js fiddle for edit and delete

I am not able to get updated Content on Done click,what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: The down votes are probably because you haven't asked a specific question, any errors? Your current "question" includes a lot of guess work

Comment: What guess work? I have provided complete code and specified that i am not getting the updated content after clicking on Done. I guess i have provided everything i can

Comment: So what is happening? Does the code compile? Have you set breakpoints and found any code not running? Any errors?

Comment: NO errors and code compiles well. Now after editing and clicking on done it should show edited content as well, but it is not :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe `event.preventDefault` to prevent the default behaviour of anchor tag

```
 $('#done1').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("newpanel1").contentEditable = "false";
    document.getElementById("collapseTwo").contentEditable = "false";
    //$("#myContent").val($("#panel1").html());
    $('#newpanel1').attr('style', 'border:none;');
    $('#collapseTwo').attr('style', 'border:none;');
    $('#edit1').attr('style', 'display:block;');
    $('#done1').attr('style', 'display:none;');

 });
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wf8yJ/9/)

Comment: I guess you did not get my question sir,when i edit and click done i want page to show edited too,but it goes back to show original data