# Edit each div separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a div and it can edit only div having particular ID

Now since I am showing each div from database list, how can i Edit each div separately.
Hope i am Clear.Thanks

Comment: so do you have edit, done and hide button for each div?

Comment: Yes i have for each div . As i am showing list from DB and foreach, Edit and delete button gets added for each div but only div having ID panel is getting edited.

Comment: what is this => "@Html.DisplayFor" ?? @Html stands for what? Such thing is not there in jQuery, neither in jScript.

Comment: @PratikJoshi That is Razor code to display item from list

Comment: @RS26  , sorry but in asp.net i never coded like that!

Comment: Razor is new and it is simplest way to display data from model to view. I am doing it as an MVC application

Comment: in the loop ids should be generated unique to each element.

Comment: You have same ids in foreach ,which is sin in javascript.

Comment: Is there any way i can make div editable based on if it selected or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID attribute must be unique.

If not needed remove the id's from your html elements, and use only class's and DOM hierarchy to find and handle your DOM object accordingly.

Something like, this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.edit-link').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings('.panel-title').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
        $(this).closest(".panel").find('.panel-collapse').attr('contenteditable', 'true');        
        $(this).siblings('.panel-title').attr('style', 'border:2px solid;');
        $(this).closest(".panel").find('.panel-collapse').attr('style', 'border:2px solid;');
        $(this).attr('style', 'display:none;');
        $(this).siblings('.done-link').attr('style', 'display:inline:block;');

    });

    $('.done-link').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings('.panel-title').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
        $(this).closest(".panel").find('.panel-collapse').attr('contenteditable', 'false');   
        $(this).closest('.panel-title').attr('border:none;');
        $(this).closest(".panel").find('.panel-collapse').attr('style', 'border:none;');
        $(this).attr('style', 'display:block;');
        $(this).siblings('.done-link').attr('style', 'display:none;');

    });

    $('.delete-link').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings('.panel-title').text('');
    })

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wf8yJ/8/

Comment: Thanks, but it just makes Heading editable and not the other part of div??

Comment: @RS26 fixed, see the edit; but please look deeply the code and try to understand it, if you need clarifications ask them here

Comment: Thanks a lot, there were few more changes but i fixed it.Thanks Sir

Comment: Sir would you please help me with this if possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759545/showing-edited-content        Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this

```
$('.edit-link').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().attr("contentEditable",true);
    $(this).parent().next(".panel-collapse").attr("contentEditable",true);


    $(this).parent().attr('style', 'border:2px solid;');
    $(this).parent().next(".panel-collapse").attr('style', 'border:2px solid;');
    $(this).attr('style', 'display:none;');
    $(this).next(".done-link").attr('style', 'display:inline:block;');

});
```

It can be reused..

Answer (score 0):

Please do not define `id` in a loop. In HTML id should be `Unique` in a document.

Better specify a class to identify the div for each item. Note that ids are removed and added a class to identify each div

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
 <div class="panel panel-default main-panel">
  ..
   <h4 class="panel-title newpanel">
```

Then attach your events that listen to the classes

```
  $('.newpanel').on('click','.edit-link', function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another edit link as your edit link makes all div s editable at once. But as convention, id on an html page should be only one.